# Is there a way to save images without white space?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

I have two issues regarding white space in images. I am trying to train a semantic segmentation model, but am having two issues with how my data is currently being stored.

Firstly, if I use plt.savefig() the images are being stored with a thin white border as below. This is using bbox_inches='tight':

[image: Thin white border]

The second issue is in how I am storing the masks for my training data. This shows the wheel tracks:
[image: Wheel Track mask]

However, in order use this as my mask layer it needs to have separate labels - what is white here, and shows 'background', should just be labelled 0 and the red should be labelled '1'. I don't quite know how to do this and googling doesn't lead me anywhere - the main issue is that the background of this image (generated with plt.fill()) is white which I think is causing issues.

Comment: You're asking a whole bunch of questions here. Break your problem down into pieces and try to solve each one. Ask a question when you run into trouble with that.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, reading different other questions and reading savefig documentation, I got here:

`plt.savefig('your_image.png',bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0)`

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to work through pixel to pixel and check if the color is white try using

from PIL import Image
r,b,g,p = picture.getpixel( (0,0) )
print("Red: {0}, Green: {1}, Blue: {2}".format(r,g,b))

Here you will get to know what is RBG color of that pixel and after this, you can change pixel color using

Image.putdata(data, scale, offset)

Copy pixel values from a sequence object into the image, starting at the upper left corner (0, 0). The scale and offset values are used to adjust the sequence values:

pixel = value * scale + offset

If the scale is omitted, it defaults to 1.0. If the offset is omitted, it defaults to 0.0.